# Slide Toggle menu won't stay opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('span.nav-btn').click(function () {
        $('ul#menu').slideToggle();
    })  
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ( $(window).width() > 900) {
        $('ul#menu').removeAttr('style')
    }
});

$('span.sub-btn').click(function () {
        $('ul#sub').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); return ('false');
    })

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ( $(window).width() > 900) {
        $('ul#sub').removeAttr('style')
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hnhea

when browser width scaled down to 900px or so, inside the "MENU" when product & service clicked the script is still working but when mouse goes over the other place, the sub menu is hidden and make it looks like :hover.

Does someone have a solution how to make the sub menu still show even mouse was in other place???

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your code here (Not in link)

Comment: would you tell me how to post it???

i'am new here

Comment: @DreLouderReaper edit the question rather than pasting it in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to separate your style rules for different viewports.

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pFtuh

You will obviously have to tidy it up.

**For example*:**

```
#menu ul {
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  display: none;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  /*opacity: 1;*/
  /*visibility: visible;*/
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
  #menu ul {
    position: relative;
    ...
  }
  #menu li:hover > ul {
     display: none;
  }
...
```

***The only changes that have been made.**

When the dropdown is in mobile viewport, you dont want the hover. 
You also want to position relative when in mobile viewport.